# Idea's for homework

Tags: java

I am not looking for a code solution for my homework, just some ideas on what to do.

Inputs are two string parameters, where the first is greater than the second.
For example: "one", "two"; would be read as one is greater than two.

So far, I am using a LinkedList to add values accordingly, but this doesn't fully do the job (explained below). What would be your recommendation on this assignment?

(inputs:) one two, two three, five six, six one would result in this:
six -> one -> two -> three -> five
instead of: five -> six -> one -> two -> three

TLDR: LinkedList can't be used to complete this assignment. I am thinking about using a doubly linkedlist to store a connection between two inputs so in the above example, it would be five <-> six, resulting in a dLL like : five <-> six <-> one <-> two <-> three

What data structure would you use?

Comment: I would use whatever the Unix `make` program uses. Or `tsort`, which may be simpler.

Comment: boy, stackoverflow is not a place to get your homework done.

Comment: @shafinmahmud I'm just looking for ideas, I already have the code for this, but was wondering if there was a better way (more efficient way) than having links to the next and prev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you're going to need to do is some how store all the data that you know, i.e.  What's "greater" than what?  To do this, I'll use a `Map<String, Set<String>>`.  Mapping one string to all the strings that are smaller then it.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> greaterThan = new HashMap<>();
```

Next, you're going to need to populate this data map with some data, I'm going to do this with a simple iteration.

```
// Example Input
String[][] inputs = new String[][]{
        {"one", "two"},
        {"two", "three"},
        {"five", "six"},
        {"six", "one"}
};

// Populate
for (String[] pair : inputs) {
    String bigger = pair[0];
    String smaller = pair[1];

    if (!greaterThan.containsKey(bigger))
        greaterThan.put(bigger, new HashSet<>());
    greaterThan.get(bigger).add(smaller);

}
```

Next, we're going to need to get all the data we need to sort, in this case.  I'm going to use a `Set<String>` in order remove duplicates then I'll convert it to a list.

```
Set<String> dataSet = new HashSet<>();
for (String[] pair : inputs) {
    dataSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(pair));
}
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(dataSet);
```

And lastly we need to sort that list using the map we created before.

```
data.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    if (greaterThan.getOrDefault(o1, Collections.emptySet()).contains(o2))
        return 1;
    else if (greaterThan.getOrDefault(o2, Collections.emptySet()).contains(o1))
        return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

And that's it!  Now print the results!

```
System.out.println(data); //Output: [three, two, one, six, five]
```

It should be noted that this could be written much more efficiently by doing multiple steps at the same time (like collecting the data & adding the data to the mapping), but here's somewhere to start!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was thinking about using Maps but was not sure how to start it. Exactly what I was looking for, thanks again!